# How does ccnet.xsd works

Tags: xml, xsd, cruisecontrol.net

All, Forgive me I am just newbie for CruiseControl.net. After read some tutorial about how to get start with it . I found actually it is important to understand what can be allowed to write in the `ccnet.config` file. and How it is works.

So I tried to figure out what is inside the `ccnet.xsd` and `CCNetConfigBuilder.xsd`.  Here it is .I just show it in the xmlspy 2010.

[image]

[image]

From the schema of cc.net. In my understanding. The root element of configuration is `cruisecontrol`. 
and the sub elements of it could be `project`, `queue`, `cb:define` or `cb:scope`. these elements can be Occurs times from "0"  to "unbounded".

But When I looked at the examples of ccnet.config from http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Step_2_Build_on_Check-in

For example:

```
<cb:scope ProjectName="ProjectX">
  <cb:define ProjectType="_CI" />
  <project name="$(ProjectName)$(ProjectType)" queue="Q1" queuePriority="901">
     .....
  </project>
</cb:scope>
```

What makes me confused is:

Why the `cb:scope` can be the father node of `project`? Because I didn't see this parent and child relationship is defined in the cc.net xsd.( Please correct me if I am wrong.)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there are two XSD documents. The cb namespace is used by the configuration builder which is a pre-processor for the CruiseControl.NET configuration files. The project element is a CruiseControl.NET element which is described in the CruiseControl.NET schema CCNet.xsd used for the default namespace.

```
<cruisecontrol 
    xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://...path to file on disk..//ccnet.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema file://...path to file on disk..//ccnet-config-builder.xsd"
    xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/8">

</cruisecontrol>
```